# Editing SWF or FLA files

Tags: file, flash, edit, fla

I have one SWF file and i have few URLs inside, that i want to change. My question is how can i edit SWF file? Or when i decompiler it into FLA file, how can i edit it and compiler it againt back to SWF file? I decompiler it with Sothink SWF Decompiler, try to edit the FLA file with Adobe Flash Proffestional, but the program show me only images, without script.... So i have it in FLA file, but i have no idea how to edit it and how to compiler it again into SWF file. Can you please help me do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may refer to [Can I change an ActionScript string literal in a SWF without the source FLA file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398180/can-i-change-an-actionscript-string-literal-in-a-swf-without-the-source-fla-file) for help. [Softonic SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/help/faq.htm) allows you to edit the ActionScript code.